# How to center a large image within a smaller div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Using Bootstrap 4, I am trying to add a image inside of a smaller div and want to center the image and hide the area that overflow the parent div. How can I do this?

Here is a snippet:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="jumbotron p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
  <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/COO8G.jpg">
    <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Sample</h1>
    <p class="lead my-3">Sample Text</p>
    <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Sample</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** The image was added as a child to the div `col-md-6 px-0` in an effort to make it responsive.

**Edit 2:** I don't want to change the size of the image. I want to keep the size, center it vertically and horizontally within the parent div, and hide the parts that are flowing over.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet. I have given 100% width and height to the image. Since it is inside a container, the image will be enlarged up to the container only. And I saw in comments that you want the image to be zoom. So I added a bootstrap modal as well.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pop').on('click', function() {
   $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
   $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
  });  
});
```

```css
img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="jumbotron p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
  <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
  <a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://experienceperception.com/images/moe1700_2.jpg"></a>
    <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Sample</h1>
    <p class="lead my-3">Sample Text</p>
    <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Sample</a></p>
  </div>
</div>


<!--Zoom image with a modal-->

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

uses the grid system classes `justify-content-center`, check the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning, I would suggest to add a class to the container for relative positioning

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
.col-md-6.px-0 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="jumbotron p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
      <img src="http://experienceperception.com/images/moe1700_2.jpg">
      <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Sample</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">Sample Text</p>
      <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Sample</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Best to add a class to the container

```
<div class="col-md-6 px-0 abs-center">
```

and then

```
.abs-center {
  position: relative;
}
```

This centers the image horizontally and vertically on initial load, if you are trying to achieve something else, please update the question

Comment: @cfoster5 my solution remains unchanged, it is as you asked in the question